# How do I make a menu and title section sticky using Divi?

Tags: html, css, menu

I am building a website using Divi, and for a couple of the pages there is a requirement to have a sticky menu, along with a top title section combined as though they were one.  Ideally I would like them to remain in their current position and simply scroll with the page without knocking out the formatting.

Code used so far is as follows:

```
.stickyheader{
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 55px; 
}
#page-container{
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

I have tried naming both the title section and menu section with the class name 'stickyheader' in the hope that both would be lumped together.  This does appear to make both elements scroll with the page, but the formatting goes out the window and they start overlapping and squashing up at the top of the screen, plus the space at the top of the title section has increased which throws the formatting out for the whole page, as everything has been adjusted to fit over the background image.

Both sections are global, for ease across all other pages as these two elements appear the same on each one.

Does anybody have any suggestions?  Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing, you can do that easily, making sure that you are using the latest Divi version which has the Theme Builder. With it, you can design a template which can govern a specific page and you can assign a fixed position to any element:

[image]

No need to use CSS. You can also take other approach:

https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/how-to-create-a-fixed-header-with-divis-position-options

https://divilife.com/how-to-make-to-your-divi-4-0-header-fixed-or-sticky/

https://www.divithemeexamples.com/make-your-divi-4-0-header-sticky-or-fixed-with-the-theme-builder/